# i need to update all records from column in other blank column in same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to update B.image_path value into A.IMAGE_DESC in same table please suggest its not working am i right:

```
update images_back_13 A
set A.IMAGE_DESC = (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(B.image_path,'([0-9A-Z])\w+')
                    FROM images_back_13 B
                    where A.IMAGE_ID=B.IMAGE_ID            
                    )
where EXISTS (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(B.image_path,'([0-9A-Z])\w+')
              FROM images_back_13 B
              where A.IMAGE_ID=B.IMAGE_ID            
             )
```

Comment: You could use a MERGE statement, it is simple and verbose. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need the sub-selects. Simply do

```
UPDATE  images_back_13 A
SET A.IMAGE_DESC = REGEXP_SUBSTR(A.IMAGE_PATH....)
WHERE REGEXP_SUBSTR(A.IMAGE_PATH....) IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a **MERGE** statement with only an **UPDATE** clause.

```
MERGE INTO images_back_13 a 
USING (SELECT Regexp_substr(image_path, '([0-9A-Z])\w+') image_path 
       FROM   images_back_13) b 
ON (a.image_id= b.image_id) 
WHEN matched THEN 
  UPDATE SET a.image_desc = b.image_path;
```